# How can I do mapping from AggregationOutput to a POJO?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

For a complicated query I descended to MongoDB Java API (using Spring-data for most of my stuff) and I wrote a aggregate statement using BasicDBObjects.

```
DBCollection users = mongoOperations.getCollection("users");

    AggregationOutput aggregationOutput = users.aggregate(
            new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("_id", userId)),
            new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("userProfile.vitals", 1)),
            new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$userProfile.vitals"),
            new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("userProfile.vitals.type", type.name())),
            new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("userProfile.vitals.observationDate", -1)),
            new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1)
    );
```

This query works, my question is not related to this statement.

The result of this aggregation is still something that fits perfectly in my POJO (no $group in my aggregate).

If I would have used the Criteria API to the query, I would get a User object back. In the AggregationOutput#results() I have a DBObject.

Is there a way to call the converters that would internally be used to convert the DBObject to my POJO directly?

I tried

```
mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(User.class,result);
```

but that threw an exception that it was not able to instantiate java.util.List. Which makes sense since that's an interface.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Kristof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page of unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/)

> $unwind returns one document for every member of the unwound array
>   within every source document.

And you wrote:

> The result of this aggregation is still something that fits perfectly
>   in my POJO (no $group in my aggregate).

Which is a wrong assumption! Unwind **does** affect the structure of the documents returned and your POJO no longer fits to the results.

In this case, you are unwinding the vitals array. The returned documents don't contain a list of vitals. Instead, each user document has a vitals object. This structural difference is causing the mapper to fail, since it is expecting a List of vitals but is getting a vital object instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a separate class ( AggregatedUser.class ) where you can map directly the output result instead of User POJO mapping.

There are a some reasons why I would do that:

- It's easy to build it
- don't discard meta information of the aggregation output that can be useful in the future
- once you start using `$project` you will need it

Regarding the spring adapter to perform this I'm not aware that it's possible. I can be wrong though.

N.